# Get Guid lookup table from custome Field in Microsoft Project Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, console-application, project-online

in this case i have custome field namely "Project Phase" then in value based on Lookup Table. 
[image]

how can i get guid or internal name like '**Entry_d4399450ea69e61180cb00155d18530e**' based on **Delay** value that appear in above image. this internal name i will use for updating data using C# Console.

here my simple code, but it doesn't VALID:

```
var PrjList = projContext.LoadQuery(projContext.CustomFields.Where(proj => proj.Name == cFieldName));
projContext.ExecuteQuery();
Guid pGuid = PrjList.First().Id;

Console.WriteLine(pGuid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally i got simple linq query in ms project to get internal name of lookup based on custome field. here is my codeand it worked:

```
var InternalNameLookup = pubProj.CustomFields.LookupEntries.Where(x => x.FullValue == "Delay").First().InternalName;
```

this code will display internal name "**Entry_d4399450ea69e61180cb00155d18530e**". this is that i need to update my custome field based on lookup field.